# How to create solr service for starting solr on reboot

Tags: bash, solr, boot, rhel

I am trying to create a solr service script that I can use to start solr automatically on reboot.  Here is a script I saw recommended:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Starts, stops, and restarts Apache Solr.
#
# chkconfig: 35 92 08
# description: Starts and stops Apache Solr

SOLR_DIR="/var/www/html/fas/solr/solr-latest"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -DSTOP.PORT=8983 -DSTOP.KEY=mustard -jar /var/www/html/fas/solr/solr-latest/server/start.jar"
LOG_FILE="/var/log/solr.log"
JAVA="/bin/java"

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting Solr"
        cd $SOLR_DIR
        $JAVA $JAVA_OPTIONS 2> $LOG_FILE &
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping Solr"
        cd $SOLR_DIR
        $JAVA $JAVA_OPTIONS --stop
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

I think I have set the appropriate values for the variables in the script. But when I try to run the script, I get "Connection refused."

```
$ service solr stop
Stopping Solr
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I get the same result whether I run the script as root or not.

I can stop and start solr this way, though:

```
/path/to/my/solr/bin/solr start
```

So I also tried creating this script at /etc/init.d/solr-start

```
#!/bin/sh

# Starts Apache Solr.
#
# chkconfig: 35 92 08
# description: Starts Apache Solr

/var/www/html/fas/solr/solr-latest/bin/solr start
```

This script works at the command line, but it doesn't work on reboot. To try to make it run on reboot, I did...

```
sudo systemctl enable solr-start
```

But solr is not started on reboot.

My versions:
RHEL 7, Solr 6.6.6

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you're providing nearly no details about your specific Solr installation. The following systemd unit example might provide a starting point though.

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/solr.service` with the following content (and perform adaptions to make it suitable to your Solr installation):

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache SOLR
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
Before=multi-user.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
User=solr
# Assumes SOLR_PID_DIR; change port if it differs
PIDFile=/var/lib/solr/solr-8983.pid
# Assumes proper configuration in /etc/default/solr.in.sh
Environment=SOLR_INCLUDE=/etc/default/solr.in.sh
ExecStart=/path/to/my/solr/bin/solr start
ExecStop=/path/to/my/solr/bin/solr stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Perform the following commands either as root or prefix them with `sudo`:

- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl enable solr.service`
- `systemctl start solr.service`
- `systemctl status solr.service`

If you need different (or more) options in the systemd unit, this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/hammady/3d7b5964c7b0f90997865ebef40bf5e1) was [suggested to upstream](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10905) as possible starting point for upstream inclusion.